# What is a jsl tag

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, jsl

Google maps place review commentaries page has a `jsl` tag, encapsulating almost the entire `body` of the page.

I tried to scrape tags but everything encapsulated by `jsl` is not recognized (tried `scrapy`'s `scrapy shell` and `beautifulSoup`, both with xpath syntax. Also tried to use `lxml` library, without success).

There is not much information about this tag in `stackoverflow` and also in a google search, and I didn't understand anything about what I have found.

What is a `jsl` tag, and how can make it to be detected by a `selector`? Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSL appears to be an XSLT variant for applying templates to webpages - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jelly/libs/jsl/index.html